The final render output and viewport render result are different
Hello Blender experts,
I am learning Blender and have trouble with the topic above(title).
The attachment illustrates that the 3D environment setup doesn't work in the final render outcome. Unlike the viewport render, it seems the HDRI and Area light are not properly blocked in the final render. Although I have checked the object properties menu in the viewport section etc., I was not able to find out something wrong and how to solve this.. please share your insight if I missed something.
Thank you!


You have an area light hidden in the viewport but not in render, that could be it:


-0- you were right! I was so stupid... Thank you very much lol
